# How to construct on statement from the dictionary

Tags: python

I have a method `contains(my_d, key, value)` what will check if the key and value exist as a pair in `my_d`.

Now, I have another dictionary `a`, and I need to run `contains(my_d, key, value)` for each key-value pair in `a` like this:

```py
a = {'employee': ['Abc'], 'type': ['A,B'], 'Desig': ['L1']}
```

I would like to generate a statement that produce that same expected output as:

```py
contains(my_d, 'employee', ['Abc']) and contains(my_d, 'type', ['A,B']) and contains(my_d, 'Desig', {'L1'})
```

Another example:

```py
a = {'type': ['A,B'], 'Desig': ['L1']}
contains(my_d, 'type', ['A,B']) and contains(my_d, 'Desig', {'L1'})
```

How do I do this dynamically?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @mkam my bad edited

Comment: Is the output a string?

Comment: @deecue not a string

Comment: oh so you mean there is a function `contains` and a variable `my_d` and you want to run `contains` on each entries in the `a`?

Comment: @deecue  yes its like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An an other solution

```
def transform(my_d):
    return " and ".join([f"cointains(my_d, '{k}', {v})" for k, v in my_d.items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = {'employee': ['Abc'], 'type': ['A,B'], 'Desig': ['L1']}

for k, v in a.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        new_v = set(v)
        a[k] = new_v

expression = all([contains(my_d, k, v) for k, v in a.items()])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Why do you convert a list of length 1 into a set? Plus, the author didn't ask to convert into a set tho.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
string = ""
for key, val in a.items():
  string += f"contains(my_d, '{key}', '{val}') and "
string = string[:-5] # to exclude the last 'and'
```

Comment: use a.items() in the for loop.

Comment: oh yeahh, missed that...i've updated my answer now =)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the built-in `all` method of python.
First, you build a generator from calling `contains` for each item in `my_d`.
And then you pass the generator to the build-in `all` method.

```py
all(contains(my_d, key, value) for key, value in a.items())
```

What the generator does is that it will check each of the returned value in `contains(my_d, key, value`. If it found at least one `False`, it will immediately return `False`. If none of them is `False`, it will return `True`. This is logically equivalent to

```py
contains(my_d, key1, value1) and contains(my_d, key2, value2) and ... and contains(my_d, key_last, value_last)
```